# Create group of rows in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple rails application with a table created using the `rails generate scaffold` command. It allows the user to add the names of different movies using a form i.e. automatically generated by rails. I want to add an option where a User can add the name of a director like `Christopher Nolan` and then add the name of all the movies of that director within it, sort of like a group in the rows. Also all the subrows need to be linked to each other. Is this possible on rails?

P.S. I know that Stack Overflow works on the concept where I add a snippet of code for help, but since I'm a newbie I don't have any idea about how to even start with this

Comment: This is where we generally reach for accepts_nested_attributes_for - search the Rails API, also tutorials such as Railscasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About nested model form http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

And this gem can help u for create form with list items
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon